# Display exit status code when using bash shebang option -e

Tags: bash, exit, shebang

Using the following shebang for my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

I would like the script to display the exit code whenever it exits upon non-zero status. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
trap 'echo $?' EXIT
```